# reconstruct an array to remove a parent in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i want to restructure my array so that it looks better in a json
here is a print_r of my current variable:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [item_id] => 1
        )
)
```

i want to reconstruct it be like this or similar:

**EDIT**

```
Array
(
    [item_id] = array([0]=>'2',[1]=>'1', [2]=>'1');
)
```

sorry for my poor english m(_ _)m
i just want the item_id to have multiple values.

Comment: no don wan n keys, am sorry, i just want item_id to have n values, is that posible?

Comment: How about `Array ( [item_id] => Array ( [0] => 2 , [1] => 1 , [2] => 1))` ?

Comment: I don't think you can have an assoc. array with same keys like that.

Comment: but how do i do that? have you any code to convert(not manual) from before to after?

Comment: The whole point of array keys is their uniqueness. You'd better explain why you need this.

Comment: I do not mean to sound arrogant, but this is basic stuff. Have you even put any effort into figuring it out yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The hurdle

You actually can't in any way produce the output that you desire, since the key needs to be unique.

You can't use a key of `item_id` more than once, every time you try and set it, it will override what was in there last.

Think about it, how do you then look up the item with key of item_id, you can't, because three things would have that same key.

If the only reason is for cosmetics, I'd leave the output as you currently have it, although it may look a little messy in your JSON, it works.

### A different approach

The best you can hope, is to get an output of:

```
'item_id' => array(
    2,
    1,
    1
)
```

You can do this with the help of the [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function:

```
$array = array('item_id' => array_map('current', $array));
```

Comment: tis is the answer am searching tank you m(_ _)m. i shall reconstruct my question for better purpose.

Comment: you should then upvote / accept answers that were helpful to you, to help the community when someone else comes across this question, so they can know what helped you out.

Comment: i cannot it seems i dont have 15 reputations, i shall go back when i has enough,.. some reason it +1

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using this code.

```
$a['item_id'] = array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$val) {
     $a['item_id'][] = $val['item_id'];
}
print_r($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('item_id' => array_map('current', $array));
```